# How to store semantics of mathematics in general?

Tags: math, semantics

I am trying to work on making a system that will store mathematics semantics and solve it semantically rather than on syntax. I am not able to figure out where to start. An example of my problem can be a+b is addition if a and b are integers, concatenation if they are strings . semantically I want to enter the equation and solve it depending on the domain. Please help to find the starting point.thanks

Comment: Look up articles on compiler design. This is essentially a parsing/lexing problem, which are the first two stages a compiler goes through.

Comment: Voting to close, this is way too broad a question for SO (see help centre for guidelines on asking good questions).  Rather than asking questions here your time would be better spent on the Internet with your favourite search engine.  Have a look at, for example, *computer algebra systems*.

Comment: It is a broad question. Parsing the expression to build a [binary expression tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: To do semantics of mathematics in full generality would get very complex. There is an XML format [OpenMath](http://www.openmath.org/) which tackles the problem but much more that is needed here. It might help to look at "operator overloading" which allow + to have different meaning depending on context.

Comment: You can parse expressions to content MathML (mathematics XML) and store the XML. Evaluating the expression is straightforward, just walk the DOM tree; there might already be a library function for that. Note that you want content MathML as opposed to presentation MathML which is for display only.